# Converting cell array to matrix

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB I have a 1x60 cell array in which each column is a 1x600000 double. Now my goal is to put each cell as a column in a new matrix. Does anyone know how to do it?

I tried many times but the result is always a matrix 1xsum of each column.

Comment: What do you mean that the cell array contains a "mat-file"? Please post an example of your data. It seems likely that the contents of the cells in the cell array are different sizes, which is why they were put in a cell array in the first place rather than a matrix.

Comment: A MAT-file is a way of storing arrays on disk, they cannot be inside a cell array. In the cell array you might have the name of a MAT-file, or maybe you loaded the contents of a bunch of MAT-files into the cell array. Please show some example code (read “[mre]” to learn how) that creates a cell array similar to the one you have. And show your attempts, so we know what not to suggest.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. Each column of the cell array is 1x600000 double.

Answer (score 1):

By far, the best option is to store the data as columns in your cell array or, even better, a preallocated matrix. If that's not possible, you still have a few options.

##### The problem:

Given a cell array `C` (I'll use an array with 4 cells, each cell containing a 1x5 row vector):

```matlab
C =
{
  [1,1] = 8   7   2   2   7
  [1,2] = 6   8   6   6   5
  [1,3] = 5   10    7    6    9
  [1,4] = 8   4   4   9   9
}
```

If you try to use `cell2mat` directly on this cell array, it will give you one long row vector.

##### Reshape the row vector:

You can simply reshape the results of `cell2mat(C)` from a row vector to a matrix:

```matlab
M = reshape(cell2mat(C), numel(C{1}), []); 
% or 
M = reshape(cell2mat(C), [], numel(C));
```

##### Transpose the cell array:

By transposing the cell array, you turn each cell into a row of the resulting matrix. You can then transpose the matrix to make each cell a column:

```matlab
M = cell2mat(C.').';
```

##### Transpose each cell:

If each cell contains a column vector, `cell2mat` can do the job directly. You can use `cellfun` to handle the looping for you:

```
M = cell2mat(cellfun(@transpose,C,'UniformOutput',false));
```

(UniformOutput=false is required because our cells are not scalars.)

##### Good old loops:

`cellfun` simply hides the loops from us, so we could have used a `for` loop in the previous method, but if we're already looping through the cells, why not simply store the vectors into the output matrix instead of modifying the cell array?

```
M = zeros(numel(C{1}), numel(C));
for column = 1:numel(C)
   M(:,column) = C{column}.';
end
```